# JWT-Token: Class 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel-5, jwt

I'm using this guide https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps#installing-the-angularjs-dependencies to implement JWT-token, but when I come to the section where I want to test my API i get this error:

> Class 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider' not found

No matter which route I try to access this error pops up. I'm quite new at laravel so I can't figure out what is wrong, or what I'm not doing right - Thank you.

Comment: Check if the package has been installed successfully, if yes check that you have added the service provider in config/app.php, please post error log found under storage/logs

Comment: Hi @KhanShahrukh, I followed exactly the guide. this is the error i get in the log:[2015-12-28 14:18:37] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider' not found' in /var/www/opiioapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php:146
Stack trace:
#0 {main}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who is finding this question from the scotch.io tutorial (excellent tutorial btw), the problem is that these lines:

```
'JWTAuth'   => Tymon\JWTAuthFacades\JWTAuth::class,
'JWTFactory' => Tymon\JWTAuthFacades\JWTFactory::class
```

Should be this (extra `\`):

```
'JWTAuth'   => Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth::class,
'JWTFactory' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTFactory::class
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to use facade

`use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;`

Try adding this line at the top of your controller